# XHR failed loading: POST java spring

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to send data from my jsp page to my controller with ajax.
However i cant get it done and everytime i get the error shown in the title of the post.

JSP content: (This is my modal where i load all my users, i want to add them to a project by sending both my users id and my current projects id to my controller)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1 class="text-center">UserList</h1>
                    <br><br>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Photo</th>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Function</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="u" items="${users}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="${u.getPhoto()}"
                                             alt="Alternate Text" class="img-responsive" /></td>
                                    <td>${u.getFirstname()}</td>
                                    <td>${u.getLastname()}</td>
                                    <td>${u.getFunction()}</td>
                                    <td>${u.getEmail()}</td>
                                    <td><Button type="Button" onclick="myFunction()" id="addButton" class="btn btn-default">Add</button></td>
                            <input type="hidden" id="currentProjectId" value="${p.getProjectId()}">
                            <input type="hidden" id="userId" value="${u.getUserId()}">
                            </tr> 
                        </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <script>
                        function myFunction()
                        {
                            var currentProjectId = $('#currentProjectId').val();
                            var userId = $('#userId').val();

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                url: "addUserToProject",
                                data: JSON.stringify({projectId: currentProjectId, userId: userId}),
                                dataType: 'json',
                                timeout: 600000,
                                success: function (data) {
                                    console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
                                },
                                error: function (e) {
                                    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    </script>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller content:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUserToProject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String addUser(@RequestParam("projectId") String projectId, @RequestParam("userId") String userId) {

    UUID uid = UUID.fromString(userId);
    UUID pid = UUID.fromString(projectId);
    User u = UserList.getInstance().readUserById(uid);
    Project p = ProjectList.getInstance().readProjectByID(pid);

    ProjectList.getInstance().addUsertoProject(u, p);
    return "redirect:/projectpage";
}
```

The result i get now looks like this:
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpTl4.png)

What am i doing wrong here? any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: In `$.ajax.data` you're setting POST *body*, but in `@RequestParam` you're expecting it in POST *parameter*.

Comment: Thnks! could you maybe tell me how i should do it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the parameters to the url that you would like to post, such as:

```
url: "/addUserToProject?projectId=" + currentProjectId + "&userId=" + userId;
```

And don't forget to remove 'data' section from your ajax post.

PS: If you want to use 'data' in your ajax request, you need to remove `@RequestParam` annotation from your Java method. Instead, you can create a new model class and put the parameters along with their getter and setter methods. Pass that model to the Java method using `@RequestBody` annotation. Then you can use "data" in your ajax request.

Comment: thnks for the response! i know i can pass parameters in the url but i dont want to open a new page.

Comment: When i try @RequestBody it gives me a 415 error for "Unsupported media"